# How to remove dynamic parameter in extjs in next request?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I am working on extjs 3.4.0 and I wanted to add extra parameter in request to identify whether respective button is clicked or not (lets say clear filter button).
I have added that parameter in following way-

```
tbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
    pageSize: 25,
    store: PHOPHTStore,
    displayInfo: true,
    displayMsg: 'Displaying reports {0} - {1} of {2}',
    emptyMsg: "No reports to display",
    plugins: [PHOPHTFilters],
    items:['-',{
        text: 'Clear Filters',
        iconCls:'x-btn-text-icon',
        icon:'../images/tmp/cancel.gif',
        tooltip:'Clear currently applied filters',
        handler: function() { 
            PHOPHTGrid.filters.clearFilters();
            PHOPHTStore.load({ params: { actionFilter: "clear" } }); 
        }
    }
})
```

Now the situation is I have added this `{ actionFilter: "clear" }` when clear filter button is clicked.But this parameter is carried forward in every next request.I want to remove this as soon as this request is occurred OR when next request is demanded like ascending/descending column OR any other request.
I was planning to to this in -

```
listeners: {
                'beforeload' : function() {
                    loadMask.msg = "Loading Reports(s), please wait...";
                    loadMask.show();
                },
                'load' : function() {                   
                    loadMask.hide(); 
                }
            }
```

Is there any other any way to store this parameter at this button click 
OR
How can I remove this added parameter in any way?
please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Ext.Ajax.extraParams](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-property-extraParams). I use this approach when loading data from server.

Partial example:

```
xloaddata: function() {
    var me = this;

    var v = me.edit_search.getValue();
    me.store.proxy.extraParams = {
        tablename: me.xtablename, 
        filter: v
        )
    };
    me.store.loadPage(1);
    me.store.proxy.extraParams = {
        tablename: me.xtablename
    };
}
```

Comment: but this will not setting parameter when button click at browser rather it is assigning parameter when data gets loaded from server.

Comment: @Exception Yes, I thought that this was your case. I just don't use 'params' and pass everything I need with 'extraParams'. Sorry, if I've misunderstood your question.